# set different layout for different product type in magento?

Tags: magento, layout, bundle, typeid

How can we set different layout for different product according to product type?
I want to show Virtual and Bundle product in different layout, simple and grouped will show in differ layout.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "layout"? Do you mean page template or what?

Comment: We just want to change different placement of product info (description, price html, add to cart button etc.) on product detail page(view.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout catalog.xml file in layout folder of your theme.

There are several handles which might be useful for you:

```
catalog_product_view
PRODUCT_TYPE_simple
PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable
PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped
PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual
```

There you can try to change your rendering logic.

Comment: there are only 4 of product types. but where's the rest of them (bundle and downloadable)?